# How to bulk strip all rows in single query?

Tags: python, sql, postgresql, orm, sqlalchemy

I am developing an web application using pyramid web framework. I am using sqlalchemy for ORM and models. I am using postgres for DB.

I need to remove trailing whitespaces from all values of a column.

I know I can query all records and iterate them one by one and strip them.
But that would take time.

Is there a way to strip all values of the column in the table in single query?

Answer (score 0):

To remove all trailing blanks from a column:

```
UPDATE tablename
SET columnname = TRIM(TRAILING FROM columnname)

WHERE columnname LIKE '% '
```

The `WHERE` clause is there to keep transaction size down. Not required, but great if just some values need to be trimmed.

Answer (score 0):

if you just need  in select you could

```
select trim(my_column)
from my_table
```

if you want update the table

```
update my_table  
set my_column = trim(my_column)
```

Answer (score 0):

Yes possible. Just update by -

```
UPDATE your_table
SET your_column = RTRIM(your_column)
```